# socket exception in android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to write a simple UDP server for android and when I run it I get the following exception: "java.net.socketException: Permission Denied" I tried to add the permission to my menifest (`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`) but I still get the same exception.
the code that causes the exception is:

```
int in_port = 61000
DatagramSocket server_socket = new DatagramSocket(in_port);
```

Does someone know what the problem might be?

Thanks,
Binyamin

Comment: Can you post relevant section of your manifest file? Did you run this code on emulator or device?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I found a problem in my menifest file but I don't know how to delete question...

Comment: you shouldn't delete the question. Mods probably wont allow you to. If this is a duplicate however, let us know, we will flag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Could this be your solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791930/android-application-socketexception-permission-denied-no-such-file-or-directory). Post your manifest file on here.

Its also possible that your socket is in use. In this case set the socket as [reusable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#setReuseAddress(boolean))

Comment: Surely a better idea would be to post a bit of code here? Links expire, but if you had a part of the solution here, at least we could have a quick look and explore further if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please add details to your question.

If you are setting up your emulator as a server see [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/434412/Android/Mobile/Android-Emulator-as-server-Socket) thread;