# internet connection is disable in android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

i have no idea what wrong in the android emulator , I need to use internet on android emulator and show cross sign over internet connection show on home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Please add permissions to your Android Manifest xml file.

Please refer to:

[How to add manifest permission to android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169294/how-to-add-manifest-permission-to-android-application)

Comment: actually show cross sign over internet connection icon which is on home screen in android I think it means there is no internet connection but internet connection well in my system  so kind of changes need in emulator setting