# Network Connectivity Error In Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, installation, whatsapp, bluestacks

I know that there are several threads posted about this issue, however I believe my problem to be a bit different:

I have installed Android emulator on my desktop.

When i try to browse internet via the emulator, it works perfect.

But the problem is the apps that i have installed in the emulator are not able to access the internet

i installed whatsapp successfully, the registration screen loads properly, then i entered my mobile number and pressed OK button. I keep getting the following error

> Unable to connect. Please check that you are connected to the internet
>   and try again. Please reboot your phone if your connection problem
>   persists.

Its very annoying that i have been Googleing the error for weeks now and still havent reached a solution to the problem

I tried bluestacks .. i also reinstalled it as well as emulator several times... it did not help...

1000 thanks to person that helps me solve this issue..:D

Comment: have you set the [internet permission](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2169311/1204134)? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`

Comment: NO.. how to do it .. please please elaborate.. please help me fix this issue...

Comment: Have you thought of the possibility that `WhatsApp` may very well *not* work in the emulator since they may be expecting values from API calls (from a phone) that the emulator can't deliver? Why do you want to run whatsapp in an emulator?

Comment: Ya i knew it...I wanted to use whatsapp on emulator because bluestacks is giving similar connectivity error to me , i tried youwave application too for using whatsapp... but still some connectivity error... few friends of mine is currently using whatsapp via bluestack .. all of them  are having WIFI .. is my problem because i have wired internet connectivity.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2169311/1204134):

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

inside your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: :( Thanks for elaborating .. it didnt work.. i created a new app and added permission to that app..i run the new app.. it run sucessfully.. now i started whatsapp in the emulator .. still same error

Comment: I hope u meant what i did.. if not .. please elaborate.. srry O:)

Comment: so are you trying to access watzup messenger via emulator? I guess they ahve some restrictions placed on it. I don't think it would run on emulator

Comment: a friend of mine is using it on emulator.. he  personally uninstalled and reinstalled everything.. it gave the same error as i told.. he couldnot fix it...

Comment: a perfect example that the answer only expert can understand

Answer (score 4):

1. Re install emulator
2. Delete and create the emulator again
3. Check whether machine is connected to online
4. Check Android manifest to see whether application has access to internet

These are some common issues.

Comment: i did the steps 1 , 2 and 3 several times... i can access internet via my emulator browser but  whatsapp gives above connectivity error... can u pleaseeee elaborate step 4

Comment: THIS IS A COMMON ISSUE BUT STILL ITS NOT SOLVED BY YOUR REPLY...SRRY to tell this.. if this is an easy stuff.. then why is it not yet solved... CANNNN YOu think of any other approaches to solve this..??

Comment: reply .. u should be knowing how to fix this common issue... dont u..?

Comment: @Jay i think he meant that the 4 things he mentioned are some of the common ways to solve the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 2):

Add 8.8.8.8

on a Mac: System Preferences > Network > DNS 
(or equivalent for Windows)

As described here: [Android emulator not able to access the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736038/android-emulator-not-able-to-access-the-internet)

Answer (score 0):

I have installed youwave on my laptop at home and downloaded whatsapp, then registered in whatsapp. It worked perfectly without any problem.
Then I tried the same at office and it did not work. But can access the internet thru the browser. I believe that the reason is that at office I'm behind a proxy and not sure if whatsapp uses certain protocols not allowed by office proxy.

Answer (score 0):

ok... i have the same problem.
but i know, what is the best solution till now for bluestacks connection problem.
you have to install proxycap software.
make new proxy rules for bluestacks.

in c/program*86/bluestacks/HD-network.exe

this is the file that you have to make rule for.

whatsapp will work and other apps too.
but still u can't download data using bluestacks.

but yes if you have bluetooth then there is no problem. connect ur phone having internet connection.

and your rule's proxy will allow you to download data. the good thing is that 95% data is downloaded through your wired network(LAN). bluetooth connection of phone just helps you to maintain the server side connected...and now go to google store or wtever u want to download. you are good to go.

and just activate a small data pack on your phone.... thanxx.. hope that would help

Answer (score 0):

one solution can be to disable the gps, just go to advance conf. then to location and turn that off. that worked for me at least.