# Android Crash when reach getInputStream

Tags: android, xml, web-services, url, crash

I have built this code to get XML from URL
I used AsyncTask, bust app still crashing when reach the getInputStream() point

The point is I want to get XML from a url as string.

I tried without AsyncTask but the app still crash

I tried put GetXML() function out side the AsyncTask and call from within AsyncTask but still crash.

I tried put GetXML() function inside the AsyncTask and call from within AsyncTask but still crash.

anyone know what is the reason and how to resolve it? thanks

```
package com.asmgx.test15.app;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
        runner.execute();
    }




    private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private String resp;

        private void GetXML() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml");
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); // CRASH HERE
                Document doc = builder.parse(is);

            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
            }
            catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            }
            catch (SAXException e) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            publishProgress("Sleeping..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()

                // Do your long operations here and return the result
                //int time = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
                // Sleeping for given time period
                GetXML();
                resp = "Slept for 25562 milliseconds";

            return resp;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         *
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
            //finalResult.setText(result);
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         *
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Things to be done before execution of long running operation. For
            // example showing ProgessDialog
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         *
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onProgressUpdate(Progress[])
         */
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
            //finalResult.setText(text[0]);
            // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in
            // progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
        }
    }

   }
```

This is the Logicat error

```
07-04 04:49:53.433    1850-1863/com.asmgx.test15.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.asmgx.test15.app, PID: 1850
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity.GetXML(MainActivity.java:44)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:25)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:68)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:57)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
            at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity.GetXML(MainActivity.java:44)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:25)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:68)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:57)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity.GetXML(MainActivity.java:44)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:25)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:68)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:57)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-04 04:49:56.643    1850-1863/com.asmgx.test15.app I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1850 SIG: 9
07-04 04:50:31.313    1899-1899/com.asmgx.test15.app W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.asmgx.test15.app is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
07-04 04:50:31.363    1899-1899/com.asmgx.test15.app I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
07-04 04:50:31.393    1899-1905/com.asmgx.test15.app I/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger is active
07-04 04:50:31.583    1899-1899/com.asmgx.test15.app I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
07-04 04:50:31.583    1899-1899/com.asmgx.test15.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-04 04:50:31.793    1899-1899/com.asmgx.test15.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-04 04:50:32.073    1899-1899/com.asmgx.test15.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-04 04:50:32.273    1899-1899/com.asmgx.test15.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-04 04:50:32.473    1899-1899/com.asmgx.test15.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-04 04:50:32.673    1899-1899/com.asmgx.test15.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-04 04:50:32.883    1899-1899/com.asmgx.test15.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-04 04:50:33.083    1899-1899/com.asmgx.test15.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-04 04:50:33.283    1899-1899/com.asmgx.test15.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-04 04:50:33.483    1899-1899/com.asmgx.test15.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-04 04:50:33.683    1899-1899/com.asmgx.test15.app I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1365)
07-04 04:50:46.343    1899-1899/com.asmgx.test15.app D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-04 04:50:54.343    1899-1914/com.asmgx.test15.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 215K, 9% free 3170K/3452K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
07-04 04:50:57.773    1899-1914/com.asmgx.test15.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ab6ba8)
07-04 04:51:04.553    1899-1914/com.asmgx.test15.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.asmgx.test15.app, PID: 1899
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity.GetXML(MainActivity.java:44)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:25)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:68)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:57)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
            at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity.GetXML(MainActivity.java:44)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:25)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:68)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:57)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity.GetXML(MainActivity.java:44)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:25)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:68)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:57)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-04 05:15:28.973    2141-2141/com.asmgx.test15.app D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
07-04 05:15:31.803    2141-2141/com.asmgx.test15.app D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-04 05:15:33.073    2141-2154/com.asmgx.test15.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ab6ba8)
07-04 05:15:33.133    2141-2154/com.asmgx.test15.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 202K, 8% free 3183K/3452K, paused 43ms, total 43ms
07-04 05:15:33.173    2141-2154/com.asmgx.test15.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.asmgx.test15.app, PID: 2141
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.GetXML(MainActivity.java:51)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:72)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:40)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
            at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.GetXML(MainActivity.java:51)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:72)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:40)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.GetXML(MainActivity.java:51)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:72)
            at com.asmgx.test15.app.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:40)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Please put your Crshalog ?

Comment: Pless post logcat error.

Comment: Have you given the `Internet` permission?

Comment: I have posted the logicat error

Comment: the url is open for anyone. if you try to access it through browser you will see thr XML

Comment: You have not given the `Internet` permission in your manifest

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add manifest permission to android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169294/how-to-add-manifest-permission-to-android-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing Internet permission in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

[Why do you need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24505766/1777090)

Comment: Thanks this is working. I want to get the XML result in String.. I dont know how to do that. I am new to Android and Java

Comment: @asmgx may be you can start [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) and [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you missed the INTERNET mentioning in your manifest file. Have this below line in your manifest which allows you to have Internet Connection.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Hopefully this helps...

If still error persists, post your logcat as per other comments posted by SO folks

Comment: Thanks this is working. I want to get the XML result in String.. I dont know how to do that. I am new to Android and Java