# Android Login using PHP and MySql Async Error

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask

I need a little help with figuring this out, trying to wrap my head around the whole async process and do in the background()

I am getting this error message, and need a little bit of assistance on getting it to work.

> ```
> 10-20 14:50:55.826: D/request!(29163): starting
> 10-20 14:50:55.871: D/ProgressBar(29163): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
> 10-20 14:50:55.871: D/ProgressBar(29163): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
> 10-20 14:50:55.871: D/ProgressBar(29163): updateDrawableBounds: right = 96
> 10-20 14:50:55.871: D/ProgressBar(29163): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 96
> 10-20 14:50:55.961: W/dalvikvm(29163): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f57c08)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: D/dalvikvm(29163): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 231K, 8% free 10077K/10916K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163): Process: com.bobcatservice, PID: 29163
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at com.bobcatservice.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:98)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at com.bobcatservice.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:121)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at com.bobcatservice.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
> 10-20 14:50:55.991: E/AndroidRuntime(29163):    ... 4 more
> ```

And here is the source code

```
    //AsyncTask is a seperate thread than the thread that runs the GUI
    //Any type of networking should be done with asynctask.
    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

         /**
        * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
        * */
        boolean failure = false;

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();
           pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
           pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
           pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
           pDialog.setCancelable(true);
           pDialog.show();
       }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             // Check for success tag
           int success;
           String username = user.getText().toString();
           String password = pass.getText().toString();
           try {
               // Building Parameters
               List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

               Log.d("request!", "starting");
               // getting product details by making HTTP request
               JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                      LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

               // check your log for json response
               Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

               // json success tag
               success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
               if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Welcome.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
               }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

               }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           return null;

        }
        /**
        * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
        * **/
       protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
           // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
           pDialog.dismiss();
           if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }

       }

    }

}
```

And here is my JSONParser class

```
    public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        //try {
            //jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        //} catch (JSONException e) {
            //Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
       // }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Here is my manfiest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bobcatservice"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.persmisson.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>  
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.bobcatservice.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.bobcatservice.Welcome"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the `INTERNET` permission on your manifest file. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169294/how-to-add-manifest-permission-to-android-application).

Comment: The internet permission is there, that was the first thing I added, before doing the regular code.

Comment: Maybe the new `AndroidManifest.xml` is not properly applied. Try to clean the project before building, or even manually erase the `AndroidManifest.xml` file from your `bin/` folder.

Comment: did that, did a clean and a rebuild then I removed it manually from the build folder, rebuilt and the the same error.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your manifest file? Maybe we can find a typo or a syntax error somewhere ...

Comment: I wonder if this is happening because I am trying to access a remote mysql database, cant figure it out. It immediately crashes soon as I hit the Login button.

Comment: Thanks @antoniom,  I misspelled permissions,but now I am getting this error, could you help me out  10-20 15:54:44.986: E/AndroidRuntime(3544): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-20 15:54:44.986: E/AndroidRuntime(3544):  at com.bobcatservice.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:125)