# Using OpenWeatherMap API Key

Tags: android, weather-api, openweathermap

I get Exception "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Sydney". Can someone please help how to use it. 
Works fine with the web browser when i paste the following

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Sydney&APPID=ea574594b9d36ab688642d5fbeab847e

I tried the following combination as well but no luck

```
connection.addRequestProperty("x-api-key",
                    "&APPID=cea574594b9d36ab688642d5fbeab847e");


private static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API =
        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=%s";


public static JSONObject getJSON(String city) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(String.format(OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API, city));

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.addRequestProperty("x-api-key",
                "cea574594b9d36ab688642d5fbeab847e");

        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer(1024);
        String tmp = "";

        while((tmp = reader.readLine()) != null)
            json.append(tmp).append("\n");
        reader.close();

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json.toString());

        if(data.getInt("cod") != 200) {
            System.out.println("Cancelled");
            return null;
        }

        return data;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Exception "+ e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: your api key should be a get param, not whatever `x-api-key` is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1.-Add internet permission on your app 
[How to add manifest permission to android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169294/how-to-add-manifest-permission-to-android-application)

2.-Here you have an example about how implement an api call

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    JSONObject data = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getJSON("Sydney");
    }

    public void getJSON(final String city) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+"&APPID=ea574594b9d36ab688642d5fbeab847e");

                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    BufferedReader reader =
                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

                    StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer(1024);
                    String tmp = "";

                    while((tmp = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        json.append(tmp).append("\n");
                    reader.close();

                    data = new JSONObject(json.toString());

                    if(data.getInt("cod") != 200) {
                        System.out.println("Cancelled");
                        return null;
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {

                    System.out.println("Exception "+ e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void Void) {
            if(data!=null){
                Log.d("my weather received",data.toString());
            }

            }
        }.execute();

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I already have internet permission. I copied and pasted your url and it worked. Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Open Weather might be experiencing problems.
I say this because their example that they give is returning the same error message as yours is.
From their site >>
http://openweathermap.org/appid

Example of API call (does not have valid key):

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID=1111111111
```

Comment: 1111111111 is not a valid key, try with this  cea574594b9d36ab688642d5fbeab847e       then it works

Comment: sorry there is an extra "c" in the start, this one works http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID=ea574594b9d36ab688642d5fbeab847e

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. Create a class named GetData

   ```
   class GetData extends AsyncTask <String,Void,String> {

           @Override
           protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               String result = "";
               HttpURLConnection conn = null;
               try {
                   URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+URLEncoder.encode(params[0], "UTF-8")+"&APPID=ea574594b9d36ab688642d5fbeab847e");
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                   InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                   if (in != null) {
                       BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                       String line = "";

                       while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                           result += line;
                   }
                   in.close();
                   return result;
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               finally {
                   if(conn!=null)
                   conn.disconnect();
               }
               return result;
           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               super.onPostExecute(result);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }

   }
   ```
2. And then use this to get the data

   *`new Getdata().execute("your city or country");`*

Comment: ya it works only for Sydney it will be static, i want it to be dynamic

Comment: i have added the encoding schema.

Answer (score 0):

**Working sample with Retrofit**

```
    val apiService = 
    API.getInstance().retrofit.create(MyApiEndpointInterface::class.java)

    val params = HashMap<String, String>()
    params["q"] =  "London,uk"
    params["APPID"] = "b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22"

    val call = apiService.getUser(params)

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<WeatherResponse> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<WeatherResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Log.e("Error:::","Error "+t!!.message)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<WeatherResponse>?, response: Response<WeatherResponse>?) {
            if (response != null && response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                Log.e("SUCCESS:::","Response "+ response.body()!!.main.temp)

               // val tempCel = ((response.body()!!.main.temp - 32)*5)/9
                val tempCel = (response.body()!!.main.temp  - 273.15f)

                temperature.setText("${tempCel.roundToInt()}°C")

            }
        }

    })
```