# OpenWeatherMap Api give false data

Tags: java, android-studio

I use this tutorial : [Using OpenWeatherMap API Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321728/using-openweathermap-api-key)

When I use this url with the city name the name is correct. So if I put "Paris" I have the word "Paris" on my application:

```
URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+"&APPID=ea574594b9d36ab688642d5fbeab847e");
```

But when I try to do the same thing with latitude and longitude instead of the name of the city. The data of temperature, wind, pressure, ... are right. There is just the name of the city that is not right. Instead of having "Paris" I have something else.

```
URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%s&lon=%s&APPID=ea574594b9d36ab688642d5fbeab847e");
```

Example, by entering this into the browser. The numbers are reduced to two digits after the decimal point.
[image]

Comment: Can you post an example of query param values and outputs?

Comment: I put an example.

Comment: So, 50.635600 becomes 50.64. So the destination changes

Comment: `%s` is an invalid character sequence in a URL.  Did you forget a `String.format` call?

Comment: I think the precision of the coordinates are with two decimals, if I've understood your issue.

Comment: Yes you understand. How I change go have more decimals in the Url ?

Comment: @VRG no, I don't forget. I have the problem even without code. Look what I manually in latitude and longitude put in url and what the json gives me ...