# Android: Open json file from url for Realm

Tags: java, android, json, file, realm

For my android app I'm using a json file to inflate the app with content.

If I open the file from the assets folder, everything works fine. I'm opening the file simply by:

```
InputStream stream = getAssets().open("myfile.json");
```

Now I've placed the same file on a server. How should I get this file from an url? For example: http://myurl.com/myfile.json

I've tried the following:

```
BufferedInputStream stream = null;

    try {
        URL fileURL = new URL("http://myurl.com/myfile.json");
        URLConnection connection = fileURL.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        stream = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MY_LOG_TAG", "I got an error", e);
    }
```

It's not working, I'm recieving a 'Permission Denied' error. But the file is accessible. How to do this properly?

Comment: You are probably missing Internet permissions, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169294/how-to-add-manifest-permission-to-android-application

Comment: Do you have the internet permission declared in your manifest?

Comment: Please share your stacktrace, so that we know about the exact error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing internet pemissions. In the manifest add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```