# Unable to connect to local host tcp server from a client(android)?

Tags: java, android, tcp, tcpclient

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Socket sock = null;
    InputStreamReader is;
    BufferedInputStream bis;
    PrintWriter pw;
    try {

        sock=new Socket("10.0.0.2",6667);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
        out.write("hjdhfsjd");
        //send output msg
        pw=new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        pw.write("msg sent once");

        pw.flush();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        pw.close();
        sock.close();

        System.out.println("dfsdjf");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

}
```

I don't understand what could be the issue/ I ran the same as java client in eclipse it was able to connect but when i tried from emulator it is not working.I even tried with AsyncTask it did not work out.Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android.permission.INTERNET` into AndroidManifest.xml. Look at the [How to add manifest permission to android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169294/how-to-add-manifest-permission-to-android-application)