# Is there a way to programmatically change notification settings on android?

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, xiaomi

There's problem on some devices like Huawei or Xiaomi (or maybe on other devices to) with notifications.

I try to make Notification with sound and pushes, and I create `Notification` with `PRIORITY_HIGH`, but still when I install my app, in notifications settings (on Huawei) stayed that banners are disabled. And on Xiaomi in addition sound disabled too.

I've read that it's manufacture's restriction. Is there a way to get around it or change settings programmaticaly after the app installation?

Here's a screenshot of settings of my application, that are set after installation (on Huawei):
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFrCR.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if it can help you, but you have to ask permission to the user first. You need to declare permissions you need in your manifest. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2169311/10663762)'s what it looks like in the manifest.

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?