# Data is not uploading in Firebase database from Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've followed a tutorial on youtube on inserting data into Firebase database. I've created Member class:

```
package com.example.bazadanych;

public class Member {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String height;

    public Member() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setHeight(String height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

And I created code in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editName, editPhone, editAge, editHeight;
    Button btnSave;
    DatabaseReference ref;
    Member member;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
        editAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAge);
        editPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPhone);
        editHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHeight);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");

        member = new Member();

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = editName.getText().toString().trim();
                String age = editAge.getText().toString().trim();
                String height = editHeight.getText().toString().trim();
                String phone = editPhone.getText().toString().trim();

                member.setName(name);
                member.setAge(age);
                member.setHeight(height);
                member.setPhoneNumber(phone);

                ref.push().setValue(member);

            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is I can't see data on website. I enabled writing and reading by passing true value on the website. I've connected my app to Firebase and add database to my project. I don't know where the problem is. Anybody can help me?

Comment: you can store data without creating a POJO class. You just have to pass a hashMap variable in setValue method

Comment: Have you tried to attach a complete listener to the setValue operation?

Comment: I've created a constructor with parameters and try to push it but it didn't work either...

Comment: I don't know how to pas a hashMap to be honest, can you show me how to?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct. I've also checked it over my system and it is getting stored over the firebase.
[this is the output of your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Oqu.jpg)
May be there is error in your **activity_main.xml** file.
Can you please provide your activity_main.xml file.

There is naming error in **EditText id** of **phoneNumber** in the **activity_main.xml** which is not same as in **MainActivity.java** when it is initialized in **onCreate()** method. Make both of them same.
See the difference
[MainActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZP8JP.jpg) and [activity_main.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVW5D.jpg)

Comment: I've just added my .xml file

Comment: Change **findViewById(R.id.editPhone)** to **findViewById(R.id.editPhoneNumber)** in **MainActivity.java**

Comment: I had it that way, it was a problem with some configuration  in firebase website

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/adding-firebase-to-android-app/amp/

Comment: I still have a problem, do you have other ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the screenshots of stack trace of errors in your application.

Comment: I think the problem is with my internet connection, because I get no errors in the application.

Comment: Did you have provided the INTERNET PERMISSIONS in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I didn't and it helped!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169294/how-to-add-manifest-permission-to-an-application