# flutter audioplayers and just audio are not working after deployment

Tags: flutter, audio-player

I'm building a flutter web app that has an audio play button. I've used both audioplayers and just_audio. They both worked perfectly in debug mode but they didn't work after deployment.

Here's my codes. I don't understand it. Can anyboy help me?

```
final ttsAudio = await getTTSAudio(text: line, lan: selectedLanMap[index]!, speakingRate: speakingRate);
final bytes = Base64Decoder().convert(ttsAudio, 0, ttsAudio.length);

final player = AudioPlayer();

final urlSource = UrlSource(Uri.dataFromBytes(bytes, mimeType:'audio/mpeg').toString());

await player.play(urlSource);
```

Comment: Does your app need to fetch data from the internet? In that case, have you setup the permission for internet access? If no, then this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2169311/13625293

Comment: I'm build a flutter web not android app. Do I need to set the permission for internet access?

Comment: My bad, didn't read that. No, my comment was about setting up permission for Android

Comment: I'm encountering this as well, just playing from assets also doesn't work, I'm using firebase to deploy